# How/where does one get a version of the OSSEC agent-auth application that will run on Windows?

Tags: windows, ossec

I have successfully configured an OSSEC server running on Ubuntu in AWS.

I have also successfully automated Ubuntu AWS instances automatically installing the OSSEC agent and connecting to the OSSEC server via this command `/var/ossec/bin/agent-auth -m ossec.myprivatedomain.local -p 1515`

I am working on automating the installation of the OSSEC agent for Windows instances including automating the Windows instances connecting to the OSSEC server. I understand that the OSSEC agent for Windows can be downloaded from the OSSEC site's "Downloads" page and that it can be silently installed using this command line: `ossec-agent-win32-2.8.3.exe /S`

Despite much research, I cannot find out how to get a version of the OSSEC `agent-auth` executable that will run on Windows to allow me to automate the Windows instances connecting to the OSSEC server.

The closest thing I can find to any mention of the `agent-auth` application being available for Windows is from this blog:
  https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/issues/166#issuecomment-41461642
... where a comment states ...

> The Windows version of agent-auth was compiled on Linux (Fedora 20)
>   and tested on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

How/where does one get a version of the OSSEC agent-auth application that will run on Windows?

Comment: It looks to me like the code changes to add the agent-auth.exe file to the repository are still in an (unmerged) [pull request](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/pull/181) on Github. So you can either wait for them to merge the code in and issue a release, or download that branch and compile it yourself with Visual Studio.